# How to use group by with proc means

Tags: sas

I would like to know how I can get this results using SAS code. 
I have the following dataset:

```
id  2015  2016  2017
1   £10   £12   £11
2   £12   £14   £13
3   £11   £20   £10
4   £10   £13   £21
5   £15   £11   £18
```

and I want to compute the mean as follows:

```
id  2015  2016  2017
1   £10   £12   £11
2   £12   £14   £13
3   £11   £20   £10
4   £10   £13   £21
5   £15   £11   £18
Mean  £11.6   £14   £14.6
```

I thought of using proc means for do this:

```
proc means data=work.dataset1;
output out=work.dataout mean= /autoname;
var amt; 
class id;
run;
```

Now, I would need to compute the difference between periods.
I am having difficulties in grouping by variable and getting the mean as in the table above.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that first picture really how you have the data?  You cannot normally use numbers as variable names.  It might be more flexible to store the data as a separate observation per id per year.  So your dataset would have just three variables ID, YEAR and COST (or whatever name works for what you are measuring).  Then it can work for any number of years.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It was a sample of dataset to analyse, only to better explain the steps. My difficulties were in grouping by variables in order to get the mean for each time period. Right now I have multiple dates for single account (id). And I am computing the difference between the current value and the previous one using lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `class id`.  The procedure would compute the mean for each `id` group, and as such each `id` has only one row.

You show `var amt`, but the data set shown has an amount column for each year.  Do you have columns `amt2015`, `amt2016`, `amt2017` ?

You will need to use the proper syntax of `Proc MEANS`.  Example:

```
data have; input 
id amt2015-amt2017; datalines;
1   10   12   11
2   12   14   13
3   11   20   10
4   10   13   21
5   15   11   18
run;

proc means noprint data=have;
  var amt2015-amt2017;
  output out=means mean=amt2015-amt2017 / autoname;
run;

data means;
  set means;
  meandiff_1_2 = amt2015-amt2016;
  meandiff_2_3 = amt2016-amt2017;
run;

proc print data=means; run;

-------- listing -------- 
                                                            meandiff_    meandiff_
Obs    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    amt2015    amt2016    amt2017       1_2          2_3

 1        0         5        11.6        14        14.6        -2.4         -0.6
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. For each id I have multiple dates, i.e. the months of the year. For each month I can associate an amount. This would mean that I need to group by time as well (I think). The mean difference should be calculated using lag1 and lag2, inside a proc sql. I hope this can help. Please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Does the raw data have columns `id`, `date` (corresponding to a month), and `amount` ? If so, do you want the average annual amount totals and year over year deltas?  Your question might be better if you describe the actual situation and not some intermediate state.

Comment: The dataset has accounts and for each account are associated dates from 1 to 140 in terms of months. For each moth an amount is calculated. I would like to determine the average balance amount for the whole year (from 1 to 12, from 12 to 24...), not for account. I hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have the data in the format you first show?  If so what are the names of the variables?  `2016` is not a valid variable name.

Let's assume you have the data in more normalized form (or can convert it to such).

```
data have ;
  input id $ @;
  do year=2015 to 2017 ;
    input amt @ ;
    output;
  end;
cards;
1  10 12 11
2  12 14 13
3  11 20 10
4  10 13 21
5  15 11 18
;
```

You can then use PROC MEANS to find the mean amt per time period.

```
proc summary data=have nway ;
  class year;
  var amt ;
  output out=means mean=mean_amt ;
run;
```

And a simple data step to calculate the difference between the time periods:

```
data want;
  set means;
  mean_dif = dif(mean_amt);
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    year    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    mean_amt    mean_dif

 1     2015       1         5        11.6          .
 2     2016       1         5        14.0         2.4
 3     2017       1         5        14.6         0.6
```